# PHP Laravel Server Environment Configuration

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-environment

I am new with laravel and I am confused on how to setup my server environment configuration. So here is a sample code I've seen in some tutorials, but still I am not satisfied that this would be flexible enough specially when my other co-developers use it.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
'local' => ['127.0.0.1', gethostname()],
'production' => ['ipforproductionhere'] ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put in `local` names of your and other developer PC for example:

```
'local' => ['yourpcname', 'yourcoworkerpcname', 'yourothercoworkerpcname'],
```

And of all you when developing on those machines will work in local environment.

**EDIT**

You can also use other type of environment detecting for example:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function(){
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ||
        strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'.') === false) {
        return 'local';
    }
    return 'production';
});
```

Now assuming each developer create virtualhost without a dot and uses for example `http://myproject` as domain it will use `local` environment and if dot will be found in `HTTP_HOST` it will use `production` environment.

Comment: Yes I can do this, however it's a little bit messy when you have all those bunch of pc names. And how about in production?

Comment: @Cyril On production you use only one machine, look also at my edited answer